# Ubuntuserver 16.04 crashes on large data loads

Tags: server, crash

First: I am the newest newbie on Ubuntu or any other Linux for that matter.
It might explain my stupid questions.

My problem: I installed Ubuntu server 16.04.4 on some old hardware. It consists of an old Asrock motherboard, an AMD cpu a couple of hard-disks and something like 6 GB memory.
I installed Ubuntu server with Samba server and SSH-server.

It looks like everything works just fine: I can see the shares I made on my Windows pc, I have access to them and can read and write in the shares. But when I try to fill them the server crashes when offering it large amounts of data, say more than 1 or 2 GB at once. For controlling it I use Webmin and I try to familiarize myself with Linux commands, but like I said: I am the newest newbie you could imagine, so I prefer something that handles more or less like a GUI.

Can somebody please help me with this problem or point me in direction that has a chance of solving this?

Comment: Do you have `swap` space defined?

Comment: Yes I have indeed: 20 GB.